# Python loops are missing results

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am reading a file with about 13,000 names on it into a list.

Then, I look at each character of each item on that list and if there is a match I remove that line from the list of 13,000.

If I run it once, it removes about half of the list. On the 11th run it seems to cut it down to 9%. Why is this script missing results? Why does it catch them with successive runs?

Using Python 3.

```
with open(fname) as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

bad_letters = ['B', 'C', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'L', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'U', 'W', 'X']

def clean(callsigns, bad):
    removeline = 0

    for line in callsigns:
        for character in line:
             if character in bad:
                 removeline = 1
        if removeline == 1:
            lines.remove(line)
            removeline = 0
    return callsigns

for x in range (0, 11):
    lines = clean(lines, bad_letters)   

print (len(lines))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing (i.e., mutating) the `lines` array while you're looping (i.e. iterating) over it. This is never a good idea because it means that you are changing something while you're reading it, which leads to you skipping over lines and not removing them in the first go.

There are many ways of fixing this. In the below example, we keep track of which lines to remove, and remove them in a separate loop in a way so that the indices do not change.

```
with open(fname) as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

bad_letters = ['B', 'C', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'L', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'U', 'W', 'X']

def clean(callsigns, bad):
    removeline = 0
    to_remove = []
    for line_i, line in enumerate(callsigns):
      for b in bad:
        if b in line:
          # We're removing this line, take note of it.
          to_remove.append(line_i)
          break
    # Remove the lines in a second step. Reverse it so the indices don't change.
    for r in reversed(to_remove):
      del callsigns[r]

    return callsigns

for x in range (0, 11):
    lines = clean(lines, bad_letters)
```

Comment: Neat answer, thanks for sharing. Would there be a way to eliminate the need for looping through every character in the list element? Perhaps with the use of a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, you can. Regular expressions would work. You could also convert `bad_letters` to a set and use set intersection. It's not clear which of these methods would be fastest, you'd have to try them out.

Answer (score 1):

Save the names you want to keep in a separate list.. Maybe this way:-

```
with open(fname) as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

bad_letters = ['B', 'C', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'L', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'U', 'W', 'X']

def clean(callsigns, bad):
    valid = [i for i in callsigns if not any(j in i for j in bad)]
    return valid

valid_names = clean(lines,bad_letters)

print (len(valid_names))
```

Comment: Keep it short and simple :)